# PostgreSQL unescape JSON string

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm trying to use the new JSON capabilites in PostgreSQL 9.3 and I'm looking for a function that unescapes JSON, the oposite of to_json(anyelement).

Below is a sample JSON:

```
{"single_comment": "Fred said \"Hi.\"" , 
"comments_array": ["Fred said \"Hi.\"", "Fred said \"Hi.\"", "Fred said \"Hi.\""]}
```

The query:

```
SELECT json_array_elements(json_column->'comments_array')
```

returns as descibed in the documentation a SET OF JSON.

```
"Fred said \"Hi.\""
"Fred said \"Hi.\""
"Fred said \"Hi.\""
```

Is there a way to unescape the result, so I can have the following result:

```
Fred said "Hi."
Fred said "Hi."
Fred said "Hi."
```

In the documentation I don't see any function that can help me. Unfortunately insalling the PLV8 is not a option for me.

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: Err... isn't `"Fred said \"Hi.\""` just another way of writing 'Fred said "Hi."'`?

Comment: Have you tried `json_each_text` instead of `json_array_elements` ?

Comment: json_each_text works with key->value structure, i have an JSON array.

Comment: `json_array_elements_text` (instead of `json_array_elements`) does just that. Might not have been available in 2013 :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran across this issue myself, and here is how I approached it.  I created a helper function that iterates over the array and uses the ->> operator using a subscript to get the text value back.  If anyone knows a better way, I'm happy to hear about it, because this seems a bit klunky.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json_text_array_to_pg_text_array(data json) returns text[] AS $$
DECLARE
    i integer;
    agg text[];
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 0..json_array_length(data)-1 LOOP
        agg := array_append(agg, data->>i);
    END LOOP;

    return agg;
END
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Then you can do things like:

```
test=# select json_text_array_to_pg_text_array('[ "hello","the\"re","i''m", "an", "array" ]'::json);
 json_text_array_to_pg_text_array 
----------------------------------
 {hello,"the\"re",i'm,an,array}
(1 row)
```

You could also make the function just return a setof text if you don't want to do deal with the arrays directly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json_text_array_to_row(data json) returns setof text AS $$
DECLARE
    i integer;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 0..json_array_length(data)-1 LOOP
        return next data->>i;
    END LOOP;
    return;
END
$$ language plpgsql;
```

And then do this:

```
test=# select json_text_array_to_row('{"single_comment": "Fred said \"Hi.\"" ,"comments_array": ["Fred said \"Hi.\"", "Fred said \"Hi.\"", "Fred said \"Hi.\""]}'::json->'comments_array');
 json_text_array_to_row 
------------------------
 Fred said "Hi."
 Fred said "Hi."
 Fred said "Hi."
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 7):

Find something simple on an other website:
Source [here](https://dev.to/mrmurphy/so-you-put-an-escaped-string-into-a-json-column-2n67)

Details if link is dead:

```
select (ingredients #>> '{}')::jsonb->>'cheese' from pizza;
```

Do this ☝️. When you’ve got a table (pizza) with a jsonb column (ingredients), and you’ve accidentally put an escaped JSON string inside that column, instead of a JSON object. The value might look like this:

```
"{\"cheese\": \"mozzarella\"}"
```

See the quotes? That’s just a string at the root level inside of that JSON column. But what you really want looks like this:

```
{"cheese": "mozzarella"}
```

That’s better. But we’ve already made the mistake, so we’ve got to write a migration to fix the data. Here’s how we do it:

```
(ingredients #>> '{}')::jsonb
```

The `#>>` operator in Postgres gets a “JSON object at specified path as text” ([PostgreSQL: Documentation: 9.3: JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html)). Here we’re passing in an empty path to say that we want Postgres to give us the unescaped string at the root level as a `text` value.

We can then cast that `text` value back to JSON like this: `(stand-in-for-text-value)::jsonb`. And then we have a normal, parsed JSON object at the root level that we can select fields off of.

Comment: Similarly, if you stored an unescaped JSON object with a key that has a value containing escaped JSON: `select (ingredients ->> 'meats')::jsonb->>'left' from pizza;` example stored data for `ingredients` column: `{ "meats": "{ \"left\": \"salami\", \"right\": \"guanciale\"}" }`

Answer (score 2):

```
select t.comments->>0 from 
(select jsonb_array_elements(your_table.json_column->'comments_array') as comments
from your_table) as t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to achieve the result with little modification of the JSON:

```
{"comments_array": [{"comment": "Fred said \"Hi.\""}, {"comment": "Fred said \"Hello.\""}]}
```

Instead of having array of strings, now we use array of objects, and the following query works as i wanted to:

```
SELECT (json_array_elements(json_column->'comments_array'))->>'comment'
```

For now this is going to suite my needs, but if somebody knows a way how we can achieve the output from array of strings, please share it :)