# How to convert a json string to text?

Tags: json, postgresql

JSON value may consist of a string value. eg.:

```
postgres=# SELECT to_json('Some "text"'::TEXT);
     to_json
-----------------
 "Some \"text\""
```

How can I extract that string as a Postgres text value?

`::TEXT` doesn't work. It returns quoted json, not the original string:

```
postgres=# SELECT to_json('Some "text"'::TEXT)::TEXT;
     to_json
-----------------
 "Some \"text\""
```

P.S. I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19414361/562459 might help. Might not.

Comment: Similar problem with array of strings, https://stackoverflow.com/q/45243186/287948

Comment: Related: [How to convert Postgres json(b) to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20236421/1048572), [to float?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24826385/1048572), [to boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33041617/1048572)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

There is no way in PostgreSQL to deconstruct a scalar JSON object. Thus, as you point out,

```
select  length(to_json('Some "text"'::TEXT) ::TEXT);
```

is 15,

The trick is to convert the JSON into an array of one JSON element, then extract that element using `->>`.

```
select length( array_to_json(array[to_json('Some "text"'::TEXT)])->>0 );
```

will return 11.

Comment: It's a pity that `json_extract_path_text()` cannot reference the root element (AFAIK).

Comment: interestingly, there was a brainstorming discussion apparently back at the API designing stage in 2012 in which a function `from_json` got proposed, but not implemented https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/JSON_API_Brainstorm

Comment: This is outdated. See other answers for a simpler solution with current versions of postgre.

Answer (score 237):

In 9.4.4 using the [`#>>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) operator works for me:

```
select to_json('test'::text) #>> '{}';
```

To use with a table column:

```
select jsoncol #>> '{}' from mytable;
```

Comment: Seems to be the simplest solution in Postgres 9.4.

However doesn't work for 9.3.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Although the `to_json` bit is a bit confusing. Assuming you have a column of type jsonb that stores some text, this worked for me: `select (value#>>'{}')::text as value_text from ...`

Comment: @hasen The OP states he is trying to extract text from a JSON value and the `to_json(...)` is simply an easy way to create a JSON value to work with as an example in a short one line statement. Certainly you'd replace it with the name of a JSON column if you were querying a table as you describe. Also, to clear up a point of potential confusion, your cast `(...)::text` is redundant as the `#>>` operator returns text by definition (and is the reason for using the operator in the first place). You could keep the parentheses but drop the cast `::text`.

Comment: Without the potential confusion of the `to_json()` call: `SELECT '"test"'::jsonb #>>'{}';`. The `#>>'{}'` is the important (if unintuitive) part.

Comment: Could someone spell out what `#>>` and `'{}'` are doing?  I can't quite follow this and neither term is google friendly.  This answer did fix my problem, I just want to know why.

Comment: @valadil The documentation for the `#>>` operator is [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html).

Comment: @valadil In this case, there is a top level, or root, JSON object `text`. It might look like a string but it is a JSON object. To convert that object from JSON to text, use the `#>>` operator. But that operator needs you to specify a path. The path to that root object is `{}`. So `SELECT '"test"'::jsonb #>> '{}'` means "get the object at the root path and convert it to text".

Comment: All of these `->>` and `#>> '{}'` answers go "blooey" if the value might be `NULL`. Is there a way to get the result `null` as a string when the value is `NULL`, ? (I mean without a `CASE` statement that specifically checks for `NULL`.)  E.g. in Javascript `JSON.stringify(null)` is `'null'`.

Comment: @user9645 without including exactly what you've tried and the result, "blooey" doesn't mean anything because, for example, `select to_json(null::text) #>> '{}' is null` returns true as expected and does not "go blooey". But you'll want to post a new question about that because it's not in the scope of this question.

Comment: @IanTimothy - Sorry, I should not have said "blooey" what I mean is that when the input is `NULL` the output ought to be `"null"` (a string), not `NULL`.  I don't see any way to make that happen without a CASE statement that checks for `NULL`.

Answer (score 29):

Mr. Curious was curious about this as well. In addition to the `#>> '{}'` operator, in 9.6+ one can get the value of a jsonb string with the `->>` operator:

```
select to_jsonb('Some "text"'::TEXT)->>0;
  ?column?
-------------
 Some "text"
(1 row)
```

If one has a json value, then the solution is to cast into jsonb first:

```
select to_json('Some "text"'::TEXT)::jsonb->>0;
  ?column?
-------------
 Some "text"
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 11):

->> works for me.

postgres version:

```
<postgres.version>11.6</postgres.version>
```

Query:

```
select object_details->'valuationDate' as asofJson, object_details->>'valuationDate' as asofText from MyJsonbTable;
```

Output:

```
  asofJson       asofText
"2020-06-26"    2020-06-26
"2020-06-25"    2020-06-25
"2020-06-25"    2020-06-25
"2020-06-25"    2020-06-25
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, i corrected the version above

Comment: Original question is how to get a JSON string's value as text with (no object key). This answer is just the difference between `->` and `->>` when using a key. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31757242/912717) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58755595/912717).

Comment: This one is correct!

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this challenge as well. If you have something that is a 'mulitselect' json you can use

select
jsonb_array_elements_text(yourjsoncolumn)
from
yourtable

to convert the list to individual text elements. If I do the other suggestions above I still get the quoted json value.

Comment: `yourjsoncolumn ->> 0` would certainly work for you, but return only the first value not every element of the array. `jsonb_array_elements(yourjsoncolumn) #>> '{}'` would also work, but of course be uglier - if you have a JSON array, `jsonb_array_elements_text` is definitely the way to go

Answer (score -2):

An easy way of doing this:

```
SELECT  ('[' || to_json('Some "text"'::TEXT) || ']')::json ->> 0;
```

Just convert the json string into a json list