# Extract an int, string, boolean, etc. as its corresponding PostgreSQL type from JSON

Tags: json, postgresql

I feel like I must just be missing something simple here, but I've looked through PostgreSQL's documentation on JSON and the JSON operators and functions and don't see anything explaining it.

It's easy to turn things into JSON in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT *, pg_typeof(j) FROM (VALUES
(to_json(5)),
(to_json(true)),
(to_json('foo'::TEXT))
) x (j);
```

will give me back a nice result set full of `json`s:

```
   j   | pg_typeof
-------+-----------
 5     | json
 true  | json
 "foo" | json
```

But how do I convert these `json` values *back* into their original types? I don't expect to be able to do that all in one result set, of course, since the types aren't consistent. I just mean individually.

## Lots of stuff I tried

Casting sure doesn't work:

```
SELECT to_json(5)::NUMERIC;
```

gives

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type json to numeric
```

If I try to abuse the `json_populate_record` function like so:

```
SELECT json_populate_record(null::INTEGER, to_json(5));
```

I get

```
ERROR:  first argument of json_populate_record must be a row type
```

In PG 9.4, I can pretty easily tell the type: `SELECT json_typeof(to_json(5));` gives `number`, but that doesn't help me actually extract it.

Neither does `json_to_record` (also 9.4):

```
SELECT * FROM json_to_record(to_json(5)) x (i INT);
```

gets me another error:

```
ERROR:  cannot call json_to_record on a scalar
```

So how do you convert `json` "scalars" (as PG calls them, apparently) into the corresponding PG type?

I'm interested in 9.3 and 9.4; 9.2 would just be a bonus.

Comment: *"In PG 9.4, I can pretty easily tell the type..."* Not really. `SELECT json_typeof(to_json(current_timestamp))` returns *string*.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Well, that isn't too surprising when you realize that JSON doesn't define a date/datetime type primitive... =) More a limitation of the JSON spec than PG. Expecting that to return something else would be a little like expecting it to return my own custom row type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way for booleans and numbers seems to be to first cast to `TEXT` and then cast to the appropriate type:

```
SELECT j::TEXT::NUMERIC
FROM (VALUES ('5.4575e6'::json)) x (j)
-- Result is 5457500, with column type NUMERIC
SELECT j::TEXT::BOOLEAN
FROM (VALUES ('true'::json)) x (j)
-- Result is t, with column type BOOLEAN
```

This leaves strings, where you instead get back a quoted value trying to this:

```
SELECT j::TEXT
FROM (VALUES (to_json('foo'::TEXT))) x (j)
-- Result is "foo"
```

Apparently, that particular part of my question [has already been addressed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27216023/1394393). You can get around it by wrapping the text value in an array and then extracting it:

```
SELECT array_to_json(array[j])->>0
FROM (VALUES (to_json('foo'::TEXT))) x (j)
-- Result is foo, with column type TEXT.
```

Answer (score 4):

First step: if your values are contained within structures (which is usually the case), you need to use the correct operators / functions to extract your data's string representation: `->>` (9.3+), `#>>` (9.3+), `json_each_text()` (9.3+), `json_array_elements_text()` (9.4+).

To select json array elements' text representation in 9.3, you need something like this:

```
select json_array ->> indx
from   generate_series(0, json_array_length(json_array) - 1) indx
```

For scalar values, you can use this little trick:

```
select ('[' || json_scalar || ']')::json ->> 0 -- ...
```

At this point, **strings** and **nulls** are handled (json nulls convered to sql `NULL`s by these methods). To select **numbers**, you need to use casts to `numeric` (that's *fully*<sup>1</sup> compatible with json's number). To select **booleans**, use casts to `boolean` (both `true` and `false` supported as input representations). But note, that casts can make your query fail, if their input representation is not accepted. F.ex. if you have a json object in some of your columns, that object *usually* have some key, which is *usually* number (but not always), this query can fail:

```
select (json_object ->> 'key')::numeric
from   your_table
```

If you have such data, you need to filter your selects with `json_typeof()` (9.4+):

```
select (json_object ->> 'key')::numeric
from   your_table
where  json_typeof(json_object -> 'key') = 'number'
```

<sup>1</sup> I haven't checked their full syntaxes, but `numeric` also accepts scientific notation, so in theory, all json numbers should be handled correctly.

For 9.2+, this function can test a json value's type:

```
create or replace function json_typeof(json)
  returns text
  language sql
  immutable
  strict
as $func$
  select case left(trim(leading E'\x20\x09\x0A\x0D' from $1::text), 1)
    when 'n' then 'null'
    when 't' then 'boolean'
    when 'f' then 'boolean'
    when '"' then 'string'
    when '[' then 'array'
    when '{' then 'object'
    else 'number'
  end
$func$;
```

Comment: The answer is kind of contained in here, but I really couldn't parse it out because there's so much going on. I've posted my own answer that I think presents it much more clearly, but thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

[This is question similar to yours.](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/52192F18.3030202@2ndQuadrant.com) Essentially, the underlying bit-level representations of the data types are incompatible, and transforming a scalar into the native type is not something that has been implemented because of the ambiguities involved. JSON has a very strict spec that corresponds tightly to javascript objects and natives.

It is possible, but I do not think it has been implemented yet.

Comment: Interesting. I suppose one could work around it with custom PL/v8 functions or something.