# In PostgreSQL, how can I unwrap a json string to text?

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have a value of type `json`, say `y`. One may obtain such a value through, for example, `obj->'key'`, or any function that returns values of type `json`.

This value, when cast to `text`, includes quotation marks *i.e.* `"y"` instead of `y`. In cases where using `json` types is unavoidable, this poses a problem, especially when we wish to compare the value with literal strings *e.g.*

```
select foo(x)='bar';
```

The [API Brainstorm](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/JSON_API_Brainstorm) page suggests a `from_json` function that will intelligently unwrap JSON strings, but I doubt that is available yet. In the meantime, how can one convert JSON strings to text without the quotation marks?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgres: How to convert a json string to text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215216/postgres-how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-text)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Text:

To extract a value as text, use `#>>`:

`SELECT to_json('foo'::text) #>> '{}';`

From: [Postgres: How to convert a json string to text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215216/postgres-how-to-convert-json-string-to-text)

PostgreSQL doc page: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html

So it addresses your question specifically, but it doesn't work with any other types, like integer or float for example. The `#>` operator will not work for other types either.

#### Numbers:

Because [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) only has one numeric type, "number", and has no concept of int or float, there's no obvious way to cast a JSON type to a "correct" numeric type. It's best to know the schema of your JSON, extract the text and then cast to the correct type:

`SELECT (('{"a":2.01}'::json)->'a'#>>'{}')::float`

PostgreSQL does however have support for "arbitrary precision numbers" ("up to 131072 digits before the decimal point; up to 16383 digits after the decimal point") with its ["numeric"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) type. JSON also supports 'e' notation for large numbers.

Try this to test them both out:

`SELECT (('{"a":2e99999}'::json)->'a'#>>'{}')::numeric`

Comment: Very good, thanks. Any idea on what to do with ints and floats?

Comment: @lucid_dreamer I added to my answer for you.

Comment: Oh I see. So `#>>'{}'` _does_ work for other types but always casts to text, thus requiring an additional cast to numeric. PS: You're very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

The `->>` operator unwraps quotation marks correctly. In order to take advantage of that operator, we wrap up our value inside an array, and then convert that to `json`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json2text(IN from_json JSON)
RETURNS TEXT AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN to_json(ARRAY[from_json])->>0;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

For completeness, we provide a `CAST` that makes use of the function above.

```
CREATE CAST (json AS text) WITH json2text(json) AS ASSIGNMENT;
```

Comment: Ugh. There must be a better way. Though I recall this being a real irritation with the 9.3 json API.

Comment: @CraigRinger Hopefully someone who knows a better solution sees this!

Comment: There's a better way now - see [the answer below by adjenks](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54047643/revisions)