# Postgres Function to Populate Recordset and Returned ID

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, insert, plpgsql

I am trying to `INSERT` a record, return the ID, and then pass the ID to other tables and insert additional data. The data to be inserted is in JSON format.

I am using a function call to insert the data, and while the create statement works, I am doing something wrong during the execution of it (so either a) I didn't write the statement properly or b) I didn't pass data in properly).

The error I am getting is such:

```
ERROR: INSERT has more target columns than expressions
SQL state: 42601
Context: PL/pgSQL function insert_to_tables(jsonb,jsonb,jsonb) line 3 at SQL statement
```

Here is how my the tables look:

```
CREATE TABLE main_data(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  field_1 TEXT,
  some_time DATE
);

CREATE TABLE locale_data(
  locale_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  city TEXT,
  state TEXT,
  address TEXT,
  main_data_id INTEGER REFERENCES main_data(id)
);

CREATE TABLE demographic_data(
  demographic_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  age INT,
  ethnicity TEXT,
  main_data_id INTEGER REFERENCES main_data(id)
);
```

I have a function like so to handle the data input and parsing:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_to_tables (
main_data_fields JSONB,
locale_data_fields JSONB,
demographic_data_fields JSONB,
OUT new_user_id INTEGER
)
RETURNS integer AS $$
BEGIN
   WITH ins AS (
      INSERT INTO main_data SELECT * FROM jsonb_populate_recordset(NULL::main_data, $1::jsonb)
      RETURNING id
      )

   INSERT INTO locale_data(city, state, address, main_data_id)
   SELECT i.id AS main_data_id, jsonb_populate_recordset(NULL::locale_data, $2::jsonb)
   FROM  ins i;
   INSERT INTO demographic_data(age, ethnicity)
   SELECT i.id AS main_data_id, jsonb_populate_recordset(NULL::demographic_data, $3::jsonb)
   FROM  ins i;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

To insert the data, I am calling the function like so:

```
select insert_to_tables(
'{"field_1": "http://www.google.com", "some_time": "09-02-2019"}',
'[{"city": "a city", "address": "123 fake road", "state": "CA"}, {"city": "little city", "address": "456 noname road", "state": "WA"}]',
'[{"age": 45, "ethnicity": "Asian"}, {"age": "45", "ethnicity": "Egyptian"}]'
);
```

My expected output should be the `main_data` table populated with 1 row, the `locale_data` table populated with 2 rows, and the `demographic_data` table populated with 2 rows.

Each of the rows in the `locale` and `demographic` table belongs to and should reference the row in the `main_data` table like so:

```
id  |         field1_1        | some_time  |
----+-------------------------+------------+
 1  |  http://www.google.com  |  09-02-2019


locale_id  |    city        |  state  |     address      | main_data_id
-----------+----------------+---------+------------------+---------+
 1         |     a city     |   CA    | 123 fake road    |   1
 2         |   little city  |   WA    | 456 noname road  |   1

locale_id  |    age      |    ethnicity   |  main_data_id
-----------+-------------+----------------+------------------+
 1         |     45      |   Asian        |    1
 2         |     45      |   Egyptian     |    1
```

I guess that my second set of `INSERT INTO` statements is miswritten, but I am not sure how to handle data insertion of JSON after returning an ID from another operation.

Comment: `jsonb_populate_recordset` return a recordset. not a string

Comment: Maybe this can work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215216/postgres-how-to-convert-json-string-to-text postgres 9.4+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem - when using `jsonb_populate_recordset()` you have to ensure that the number of json values is exactly the same as the number of table columns. You do not want to populate `id` of the tables as they are serial, so you have to indicate columns list and appropriate select list. Additionally, the function `jsonb_populate_recordset()` works on json arrays, so the first argument must be an array, like two others.

The common table expresion (with command) is a single query with several subqueries, so the function language should be SQL and the final query should return the `id` of the row inserted into `main_data`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_to_tables (
    main_data_fields JSONB,
    locale_data_fields JSONB,
    demographic_data_fields JSONB
)
RETURNS integer AS $$
    WITH ins AS (
        INSERT INTO main_data (field_1, some_time)
        SELECT field_1, some_time
        FROM jsonb_populate_recordset(NULL::main_data, $1::jsonb)
        RETURNING id
    ),
    ins_locale AS (
        INSERT INTO locale_data (city, state, address, main_data_id)
        SELECT city, state, address, ins.id
        FROM ins, jsonb_populate_recordset(NULL::locale_data, $2::jsonb)
    ),
    ins_demographic AS (
        INSERT INTO demographic_data (age, ethnicity, main_data_id)
        SELECT age, ethnicity, ins.id
        FROM ins, jsonb_populate_recordset(NULL::demographic_data, $3::jsonb)
    )
    SELECT id
    FROM ins;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

SELECT insert_to_tables (
    '[{"field_1": "http://www.google.com", "some_time": "09-02-2019"}]',
    '[{"city": "a city", "address": "123 fake road", "state": "CA"}, {"city": "little city", "address": "456 noname road", "state": "WA"}]',
    '[{"age": 45, "ethnicity": "Asian"}, {"age": "45", "ethnicity": "Egyptian"}]'
);
```

[See the full example here.](http://rextester.com/SHFQTA11451)