# Concatenation of jsonb elements in postgreSQL with comma separation

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-json

I would like to design a query where I can combine two jsonb with an unknown number/set of elements in postgreSQL in a controlled manner. The jsonb operator `||` almost exactly fits my purpose, but for one of the jsonb elements I would like to concatenate and separate by comma the two values rather than having the second jsonb's value override the first's value. For example:

```
'{"a":"foo", "b":"one", "special":"comma"}'::jsonb || '{"a":"bar", "special":"separated"}'::jsonb → '{"a":"bar", "b":"one", "special":"comma,separated"}'
```

My current query is the following:

```
INSERT INTO table AS t (col1, col2, col3_jsonb)
VALUES ("first", "second", '["a":"bar", "special":"separated"]'::jsonb))
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT unique_entries DO UPDATE
SET col3_jsonb = excluded.col3_jsonb || t.col3_jsonb
RETURNING id;
```

which results in a jsonb element for `col3_jsonb` that has the value special set to `separated` rather than the desired `comma,separated`. I understand that this is the concatenation operator working as documented, but I am not sure how to approach treating one element of the jsonb differently other than perhaps trying to pull out special values with `WITH..` clauses elsewhere in the query. Any insights or tips would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with t(a,b) as (values(
    '{"a":"foo", "b":"one", "special":"comma"}'::jsonb,
    '{"a":"bar", "special":"separated"}'::jsonb))
select
    a || jsonb_set(b, '{special}',
        to_jsonb(concat_ws(',', nullif(a->>'special', ''), nullif(b->>'special', ''))))
from t;
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                        ?column?                        │
├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ {"a": "bar", "b": "one", "special": "comma,separated"} │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

`nullif()` and `concat_ws()` functions needed for cases where one or both `"special"` values is missing/null/empty

Comment: Thanks, this worked well I didn't put this part in my question, but I updated my query to remove duplicates in the 'special' array element like so: ```WITH example (a, b) AS (VALUES 
('{"a":"foo", "b":"one", "special":"comma"}'::jsonb, '{"a":"bar", "special":"separated"}'::jsonb),
('{"a":"foo", "b":"one", "special":"comma"}'::jsonb, '{"a":"bar", "special":"comma"}'::jsonb)
)
SELECT 
  e.a || jsonb_set(e.b, '{special}',
   to_jsonb(array_to_string(array(select distinct unnest(string_to_array(concat_ws(',', e.a->>'special', e.b->>'special'), ','))), ','))
   )
FROM 
  example e;```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`jsonb_each`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) on the two values followed by [`jsonb_object_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) to put them back into an object:

```
…
SET col3_jsonb = (
 SELECT jsonb_object_agg(
    key,
    COALESCE(to_jsonb((old.value->>0) || ',' || (new.value->>0)), new.value, old.value)
  )
  FROM jsonb_each(example.old_obj) old
  FULL OUTER JOIN jsonb_each(example.new_obj) new USING (key)
)
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7fd4b20cadb9c336fa7f2ef0211d90ca))</sup>

The casting of the arbitrary JSON value to the concatenable string required [a trick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27215216/1048572). If you know that all your object properties have string values, you can simplify by using `jsonb_each_text` instead:

```
  SELECT jsonb_object_agg(
    key,
    COALESCE(old.value || ',' || new.value, new.value, old.value)
  )
  FROM jsonb_each_text(example.old_obj) old
  FULL OUTER JOIN jsonb_each_text(example.new_obj) new USING (key)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is an elegant approach, but I was hoping to only concatenate the "special" field and not all of the fields.