# How get the value of a jsonb object as text with jsonb_path_query

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

From a json object i can get the value of the requestId as text with:

```
"request" ->> 'requestId'
```

with -> i get a json part

```
"request" -> 'requestId'
```

How does it works with the jsonb_path_query() to get the value as text?

```
jsonb_path_query(request :: jsonb, '$.requestId')
```

one solution should be:

```
select test1 ->> 0 
from ( 
 select jsonb_path_query(request :: jsonb, '$.journeys[*].costs.distance.value') test1,
        jsonb_path_query(request :: jsonb, '$.journeys[*].costs.distance.unit') test2 
 from json_import ri
) foo;
```

or is there a smarter way to get the same answer?

Answer (score 2):

Extract the string from the resulting `jsonb`:

```
SELECT j ->> 0
FROM jsonb_path_query(request::jsonb, '$.requestId') AS j(j);
```

Comment: thx select test1 ->> 0 from (
select 
jsonb_path_query(request :: jsonb, '$.journeys[*].costs.distance.value') test1
,jsonb_path_query(request :: jsonb, '$.journeys[*].costs.distance.unit') test2
from json_import ri) foo; so works, but us possible to get the same smarter or shorter ?

Comment: I don't think so, but I cannot read the query in this format. Perhaps you should ask a new question about simplifying that query.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the query by selecting the "parent" object in your JSON path expression:

```
select dist ->> 'value' as test1, 
       dist ->> 'cost' as test2
from ( 
  select jsonb_path_query(request::jsonb, '$.journeys[*].costs.distance') as dist
  from json_import ri
) foo;
```

Might even be a bit faster as the `jsonb_path_query` is only called once.

Answer (score 0):

## Multiple results (jsonb_path_query)

You can use `jsonb_path_query_array` instead of `jsonb_path_query`. This will give you a jsonb-array instead of a `setof jsonb`. That again you can convert to a `setof text` using `jsonb_array_elements_text`. Example:

```sql
select jsonb_array_elements_text(jsonb_path_query_array('[{"x": "foo"}, {"x": "bar"}]', '$.x')) x
```

Result:

| x |
| --- |
| foo |
| bar |

## Single result (jsonb_path_query_first)

In case you only have a single result you can also do

```sql
select jsonb_path_query_first('[{"x": "foobar"}]', '$.x')->>0 x
```

`jsonb_path_query_first` returns a jsonb and you can use `->>0` [to get the plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58755595/327301)