# How to convert NEW/OLD object to text in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have been trying to convert OLD/NEW object to json formatted text in my function.

I tried solutions in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215216/postgres-how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-text) but it can only get a single field in json. I want to convert all object to text.

What I tried so far is something like that;

```
 CONCAT('{ "ChangeType" : "', 'INSERT',
            '", "NEW" : "',  row_to_json(NEW) ->> '{}', -- returned empty
            '", "NEW" : "',  row_to_json(NEW) ->> 0, -- returned empty
            '", "NEW" : "',  json_extract_path_text(row_to_json(NEW), '{}'), -- returned empty
             '", "NEW" : "',  row_to_json(NEW) #>> '{}', -- cannot execute json syntax error
            '" }')::json
```

I am looking this [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) but honestly could not achieve it. Basically, instead of getting single field from `'{"a": {"b":"foo"}}'` , I would like to get this object as a single text.

Do you have any idea how can I convert NEW/OLD to all text or convert JSON Object to text ?

Comment: Very simple, cast to type text, for example: `row_to_json(new)::text`

Comment: It says invalid input syntax for   '", "NEW" : "',  row_to_json(new)::text this piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are use this block:

```
CONCAT('{ "ChangeType" : "', 'INSERT',
            '", "NEW" : "',  row_to_json(NEW)::text,
            '" }')::json
```

you have incorrect syntax on this code, because you have additional quotes in this code for values `NEW`, so in JSON format, if the value of any key is JSON, it should be written without quota. Correct syntax is it:

```
CONCAT('{ "ChangeType" : "', 'INSERT',
            '", "NEW" : ',  row_to_json(NEW)::text,
            ' }')::json
```