# indexing pattern on jsonb column

Tags: postgresql, indexing, pattern-matching, jsonb

I want to improve performance of my queries using GIN index on jsonb column for pattern matching

For example, I have a table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  uuid text,
  doc jsonb
);
```

In every row of table doc has path {A,B}. B is an object, possibly empty. There is a one more *optional* element in path: it can be absent, can be C, D etc.

Can I create a single index for pattern matching that will be used in all cases listed below?

```
SELECT doc#>>'{A,B}'
FROM my_table
WHERE doc#>>'{A,B}' ILIKE '%example%';
```

```
SELECT doc#>>'{A,B,C}'
FROM my_table
WHERE doc#>>'{A,B,C}' ILIKE '%example%';
```

```
SELECT doc#>>'{A,B,D}'
FROM my_table
WHERE doc#>>'{A,B,D}' ILIKE '%example%';
```

I've tried to create index as:

```
CREATE INDEX my_index
ON my_table
USING GIN ((doc#>>'{A,B}') gin_trgm_ops)
```

Unfortunately, it works only for queries with path {A,B}, but not {A,B,C}

Comment: Do you really want to convert an *object* to text and match on that?

Comment: I suppose you could write `WHERE doc#>>'{A,B}' ILIKE '%example%' AND doc#>>'{A,B,D}' ILIKE '%example%';` to make it use the index

Comment: I think it doesn't make sense for B to be an object.  The components of a path must be either strings or integers.

Comment: @jjanes I don't think they meant that `B` itself is an object (like in `doc -> 'A' -> b::jsonb::text`), but rather that `doc #> '{A, B}'` evaluates to jsonb object value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One index might work for all the cases, but you do have to write the query in an unnatural way for ones that don't exactly match the index expression:

```
SELECT doc#>>'{A,B,C}'
FROM my_table
WHERE doc#>>'{A,B}' ILIKE '%example%' AND doc#>>'{A,B,C}' ILIKE '%example%';
```

`doc#>>'{A,B,C}' ILIKE '%example%'` usually implies that `doc#>>'{A,B}' ILIKE '%example%'`, but that is not something PostgreSQL will reason out for you.  It also isn't perfectly true in all cases, characters that require escaping in JSON will be escaped in `doc#>>'{A,B}'` but not in `doc#>>'{A,B,C}'` if the end result of one is stringified JSON object while the other is just a plain string.

```
select '{"0":{"a":"b\"c"}}'::jsonb #>> '{0}';
---------------
 {"a": "b\"c"}

select '{"0":{"a":"b\"c"}}'::jsonb #>> '{0,a}';
----------
 b"c
```

Comment: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/E7RAGPK2)

Answer (score 0):

> doc has path `{A,B}`. `B` is an object, possibly empty. There is one more optional element in path: it can be absent, can be `C`, `D` etc.

This sounds like you could pull it out to a generated column, index that and simplify those queries to just one:

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN b_c_d text 
  GENERATED ALWAYS AS
  (jsonb_path_query_first(doc,'$.A.B.**?(@.type()=="string")')#>>'{}') 
  STORED;

CREATE INDEX my_index
ON my_table
USING GIN (b_c_d gin_trgm_ops);

SELECT b_c_d
FROM my_table
WHERE b_c_d ILIKE '%example%';
```

In this [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ku30BPX5) it seems to perform slightly better, at the obvious cost of space.

Comment: This assumes an interpretation where either `B` itself holds the target string value, or there's *at most one* key under it, and if so, that key holds the target string. If this doesn't hold, it risks catching any other keys neighbouring the target under `B`.

Comment: Don't use `trim(…::text, '"')` but rather [`…#>>'{}'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215216/how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-text). This will not leave stray escaped quotes.

Comment: I think OP would need only `$.A.B.*` not `$.A.B.**`. But great idea with the generated column! If choosing the right one amongst the properties is a problem, `COALESCE(doc#>>'{A,B,C}', doc#>>'{A,B,D}', doc#>> … )` would be an alternative to `jsonb_path_query_first`

Comment: @Bergi I'll worry you even more: I used `trim()` because earlier, instead of using `to_jsonb()` like a normal person, I casually cast to `::text` *and* quote-wrapped the values with `"`, duplicating them in some places - in effect more than one had to be trimmed. Thanks for pointing this out. As to the `$.A.B.*`, it's much more tightly sticking to the spec, thus better in a way. I liked the idea that `.**` both handles the case where `B` holds the string directly and one where the nesting goes further down. Neither is required, since OP stated `B` is always an object and target is 1 key down.