where clause for jsonb array item select not working
I try this
SELECT elem
FROM jsonb_array_elements('["*", "12/05/2020"]'::jsonb) AS elem
WHERE elem::text != '*';

and this
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT elem::text 
FROM jsonb_array_elements('["*", "12/05/2020"]'::jsonb) AS elem
) elems WHERE elem != '*'

and also
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT elem::text 
FROM jsonb_array_elements('["*", "12/05/2020"]'::jsonb) AS elem
) elems WHERE elem::text != '*'

and expect as result in all cases "12/05/2020". But get "*", "12/05/2020".
Why?

elem::text is "*" and "12/05/2020" respectively, including the quotes - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215216/how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-text

indeed i already found the answer:
SELECT elem
FROM jsonb_array_elements('["*", "12/05/2020"]'::jsonb) AS elem
WHERE elem::text != '"*"';

you need both single and double quotes.
Or even better use jsonb_array_elements_text:
SELECT elem
FROM jsonb_array_elements_text('["*", "12/05/2020"]'::jsonb) AS elem
WHERE elem != '*';

